# Unable to delete items from UIPickerView based upon selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

So, I have a UIPicker view which gets populated from a NSMutableArray as long as the input is not "NULL".

So my picker shows all the values except NULL.

Now, I have a UITextField box and a button. So whatever I type in the text field, and I click the button, if it matches to anything which was there in the NSMutableArray ( which was used to populate UIPickerView ), it sets it to NULL and refreshes the UIPicker so that it doesn't get displayed anymore.

For some reason, I'm able to set the value to NULL(checked using NSLog), but the picker never gets updates, and neither does the NSMutable Array.

```
-(void) loadthepicker
{

    NSMutableArray *getarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FilerNamesArray"]];


    pickerLoaderArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {



        if ([[getarray objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"NULL"])
        {
            // do nothing..don't load


        }
        else   // add that filter to pickerLoaderArray
        {

            [pickerLoaderArray addObject:[getarray objectAtIndex:j]];



        }



    } // end of for




    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];

    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [pickerLoaderArray count];

}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return [pickerLoaderArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

The button:

```
- (IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *CheckFiltersUsed = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger myInt = [CheckFiltersUsed integerForKey:@"FiltersUsed"];

    if (myInt<=20 && myInt>0) {


        NSLog(@"number of filters used before deleting %ld",(long)myInt);
        [CheckFiltersUsed setInteger:myInt-1 forKey:@"FiltersUsed"];
        [CheckFiltersUsed synchronize];

        // get names array
        NSMutableArray *getarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FilerNamesArray"]];
        NSArray *get=getarray;


        // at location where name matches with selectedfilter..put NULL
        for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {

            if (    [[getarray objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:_filterToDelete.text]    && isFilterDeleted==NO )
            {

                NSLog(@"------currently %d is %@",j,[getarray objectAtIndex:j]);
                [getarray insertObject:@"NULL" atIndex:j];
                NSLog(@"------now %d is %@",j,[getarray objectAtIndex:j]);

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"" message: @"Deleted" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];

                isFilterDeleted=YES;

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:getarray forKey:@"FilerNamesArray"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

                 [self loadthepicker];

            }

            else
            {


                NSLog(@"No matching filter name");

            }


        } // end of for

        //now save this array back.


    }

    else
    {

        NSUserDefaults *CheckFiltersUsed = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger myInt = [CheckFiltersUsed integerForKey:@"FiltersUsed"];
        NSLog(@"Wrong number of filters!!!... %d",myInt);

    }

}
```

Comment: You have to have _something_ for every row of every component.

Comment: There's only a column, so I guess that's only one component. I'm not sure what do you mean by something for every row.

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you are trying to do, you want to delete the equal string from the array and the picker as well. But instead of that you just insert another NSString object into index 'j'

In the deleteButton method:

Instead of this line

```
[getarray insertObject:@"NULL" atIndex:j];
```

Call

```
[getarray removeObjectAtIndex:j];
```

**Update

In the loadPicker just remove the if statment to check if the string is equal to @"NULL"

So instead of:

```
for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {
    if ([[getarray objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"NULL"])
    {
        // do nothing..don't load
    }
    else   // add that filter to pickerLoaderArray
    {
        [pickerLoaderArray addObject:[getarray objectAtIndex:j]];
    }
}
```

Do:

```
for(NSString *pickerValue in getarray){
    [pickerLoaderArray addObject:pickerValue];
}
```

Comment: But the picker is loaded with all values except NULL, so this empty value will show up in it then.

Comment: Sure it will load with all values except NULL cuz when this line gets executed [[getarray objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"NULL"] you ignore all NSString objects with the value of @"NULL"

Comment: If this answer helped you please check mark it as the answer, if not please elaborate more about the problem